# How to configure filebeat.yml dissect processor for pipe separated multiline logs

Tags: filebeat

I have my filebeat.yml successfully reading a log file. Each entry in the log is multiline, and pipe separated. Something like:

```
datetime | blurb | blurb2 | <?xml><maintag .....
more xml 
more xml
more xml
</maintag>
```

The multiline processor is working correctly and creating , but I'm then wanting to use a dissect processor to strip out just the 4th part - the xml.

I have tried variants of:

```
  processors:
    - dissect:
        field: "message"
        tokenizer: "${sw.date} | ${sw.blurb1} | ${sw.blurb2} | ${sw.message_xml}"
        target_prefix: ""
```

But when I start filebeat, it's throwing:

```
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2022-10-06T08:51:42.612Z","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1022},"message":"Exiting: Failed to start crawler: starting input failed: could not unpack config: missing field accessing 'filebeat.inputs.1.processors' (source:'filebeat.yml')","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
Exiting: Failed to start crawler: starting input failed: could not unpack config: missing field accessing 'filebeat.inputs.1.processors' (source:'filebeat.yml')
```

Can anyone advise what I'm getting wrong? The message suggests to me a missing field in my dissect processor definition, but from the docs it looks right to me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ack! Found it! Would really be useful if I could learn the difference between $ and % in my tokenizer!